# Export specific data from ASCII?

Tags: python, ascii, large-files

I have an ASCII files (~70GB each) and in certain period there is result in following form:

```
Planar Power Distribution at Plane          10

    #.####   box power

     -26 -24 -22 -20 -18 -16 -14 -12 -10  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26

   -14                                   0.3821  0.8650  0.7561  0.7557  0.8641  0.3815
   -12                       0.3844  1.0520  1.0026  1.2857  0.6512  1.2853  1.0009  1.0484  0.3839
   -10                   0.8729  1.0086  1.0497  0.6109  1.1332  1.1330  0.6104  1.0469  1.0072  0.8724
    -8               0.7642  1.2983  0.6147  1.0485  2.1921  2.1344  2.1925  1.0466  0.6144  1.2983  0.7642
    -6           0.7651  0.6585  1.1432  2.2041  1.2883  1.9844  1.9849  1.2899  2.2055  1.1437  0.6587  0.7654
    -4       0.8754  1.3012  1.1442  2.1493  1.9930  2.6982  2.8647  2.7025  1.9948  2.1509  1.1449  1.3017  0.8758
    -2   0.3861  1.0127  0.6167  2.2084  1.9953  2.8720  2.0356  2.0382  2.8750  1.9969  2.2096  0.6170  1.0132  0.3863
     0       1.0589  1.0563  1.0533  1.2944  2.7073  2.0396  0.9707  2.0405  2.7089  1.2951  1.0543  1.0570  1.0597
     2   0.3862  1.0128  0.6168  2.2091  1.9962  2.8744  2.0384  2.0367  2.8743  1.9973  2.2105  0.6173  1.0136  0.3865
     4       0.8756  1.3015  1.1446  2.1504  1.9947  2.7029  2.8662  2.7004  1.9951  2.1520  1.1458  1.3028  0.8765
     6           0.7652  0.6586  1.1435  2.2050  1.2900  1.9861  1.9858  1.2899  2.2075  1.1451  0.6596  0.7663
     8               0.7640  1.2978  0.6144  1.0472  2.1932  2.1360  2.1948  1.0496  0.6158  1.3011  0.7657
    10                   0.8722  1.0071  1.0470  0.6107  1.1339  1.1343  0.6118  1.0516  1.0105  0.8747
    12                       0.3838  1.0488  1.0014  1.2858  0.6518  1.2878  1.0041  1.0539  0.3853
    14                                   0.3816  0.8646  0.7564  0.7569  0.8663  0.3828

       Maximum Pos. Maximum Value
        (  6, -2 )   2.8750
```

I need to extract these hexagons of data into one file, without the borders. Any idea?

Comment: Write a program, and if you run into problems, come back and ask for help.

Comment: You also need to be clearer about what you want the extracted data to look like. Ideally showing the result given the sample input. Lastly, what do you mean by "in certain period"?

Comment: What should be the expected result?

Comment: I liked it better when it was a red hexagon. Seriously though, @martineau how did you fix that?

Comment: The Python string method `split()` will by default split a line of text up on whitespace, so you could use it to turn each line of input for the "certain period" into a list of the just the numbers (non-whitespace) from each line. You can probably then easily format that the way you want.

Comment: @uhoh: I added `<!-- language: lang-none -->` markdown to suppress the syntax highlighting of the following code block which I found distracting.